# Django/JQuery Syntax Error: I don't know why I am getting this error

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

I am making a blog application using Django.
In my `post_save()` function in `post_edit.js`, I have this post editt operation:

```
$.post(item.find("#post-form").attr("action") + "&ajax" , data, function(result) {
    if (result != "failure") {
        item.before($("li", result));
        item.remove();
        $("ul.posts .edit").click(post_edit);
    }

    else {
        alert("Failed to validate post before saving")
    }   
});
```

So after posting the blog data to my post_list.html template, the first line of the `if` block
extracts `li` element from the result and inserts it before the "item" which is the original `li` element.

The problem is, after this operation is done, I get a JQuery Syntax Error:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: 
    <ul class="posts">
        <li>
            <a href="/post/1" class="title">NEW POST</a> 
            <a href="/save/?id=1" class="edit">[edit]</a> 
            <br /> Tags: 

            <ul class="tags">
                <li>
                    <a href="/tag/tag1">tag1</a>
                </li> 
                <li>
                    <a href="/tag/tag2">tag2</a>
                </li> 
            </ul> <br /> 
        </li> 
    </ul>
```

I am having trouble figuring out why I'm getting a syntax error, because the 
`ul class="posts".../ul` block looks completely fine to me. After debugging, I am pretty sure that
it is the 3rd line `(item.before($("li", result));)` that is causing the problem.

Can someone please help me find the problem?

Thank you

+
Also, there's another confusion.

The "result" is the `ul` block:

```
ul class="posts">
    <li>
        <a class="title" href="/post/1">NEWPOST</a>
        <a class="edit" href="/save/?id=1">[edit]</a>
        <br> Tags:

        <ul class="tags">
            ...
        <br>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I thought the line `item.before($("li", result));` 
is supposed to extract the "li" element from the result, but it looks like it is 
returning the whole "ul" block...

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: What is the value of "result" when that happens?

Answer (score 1):

```
item.before($("li", result));
```

Should be

```
item.before($("li", $(result)));
```

Or, maybe

```
item.before($("li"), result));
```

Depends on what are you trying to achieve and your HTML structure.

The source of error is that second parameter to `$` should be a [DOM context or JQuery element](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) to use as an element search tree top (i.e. only descendants are searched). With your code, you are trying to find `li`s under the `htmlString`, which is obviously an error. So, most likely it's just a missing or misplaced `)`.

You should stick with first if you are trying to find `li`s inside the returned string. Use second if you are about to insert the returned html before `li`s.

Comment: @user2436815 could you please assemble a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) example to reproduce your bug and update the question?